# How can I calculate the next birthday by computed column in ssql

Tags: sql, vb.net

i would want to calculate the next birthday of people 
in my database i have a column called dateofbirth and other called birthday
i want to be able to compute the birthday using a computed column in ssql.

(datepart(year,getdate())&datepart(day,[DateofBirth]))

i thaught i could do this pragmatically by datatable but i get an error.
below is my code.

Dim birthda As New SqlDataAdapter(birthcmd)

```
    Dim birthdt As New DataTable
    birthda.Fill(birthdt)

    For Each rw As DataRow In birthdt.Rows
        Dim dob As String = rw.Item(3)



        Dim mdat As Date = FormatDateTime(dob, DateFormat.ShortDate)

        Dim bday As Date = (Date.Today.Year & mdat.Month & mdat.Day)


        Dim yers As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, mdat.Date, Today.Date)
        Dim moths As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, mdat.Date, Today.Date)
        Dim dys As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, mdat.Date, Today.Date)
```

Comment: good but I would want to split the date of birth and automatically change the year with current year.

Comment: The SQL is irrelevant.  A `Date` is a `Date` in VB, regardless of where it comes from.  You can create a new `Date` value with the `Year` from the current date and the `Month` and `Day` from your database value.  You can then test whether that date is in the past and, if so, use `AddYears` to add a year to it.

Comment: great idea I did this but I get an error. below is my code

Comment: great idea I did this but I get an error. let me edit my question or you to see where i am getting it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for your command:

```
    birthcmd.CommandText = "SELECT        DateofBirth, " & _
                      "DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, DateofBirth, { fn NOW() }) + (CASE WHEN month(dateofbirth) * 100 + day(dateofbirth) < month({ fn NOW() }) * 100 + day({ fn NOW() }) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), DateofBirth) AS Nextbday, " & _
                      "DATEDIFF(year, { fn NOW() }, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, DateofBirth, { fn NOW() }) + (CASE WHEN month(dateofbirth) * 100 + day(dateofbirth) < month({ fn NOW() }) * 100 + day({ fn NOW() }) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), DateofBirth)) AS Diffyers, " & _
                      "DATEDIFF(month, { fn NOW() }, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, DateofBirth, { fn NOW() }) + (CASE WHEN month(dateofbirth) * 100 + day(dateofbirth) < month({ fn NOW() }) * 100 + day({ fn NOW() }) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), DateofBirth)) AS Diffmoths, " & _
                      "DATEDIFF(day, { fn NOW() }, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, DateofBirth, { fn NOW() }) + (CASE WHEN month(dateofbirth) * 100 + day(dateofbirth) < month({ fn NOW() }) * 100 + day({ fn NOW() }) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), DateofBirth)) AS Diffdys " & _
                      "FROM myBirthdayTable"
```